# How do I fix wrongly nested / unclosed HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, algorithm, xhtml

I need to sanitize HTML submitted by the user by closing any open tags with correct nesting order. I have been looking for an algorithm or Python code to do this but haven't found anything except some half-baked implementations in PHP, etc.

For example, something like

```
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo
```

becomes

```
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This is of course - generally - a "bad idea"(TM). Fixing the tags for the user may and may not yield what he intended. I'd rather validate the input, reject the update and tell the user as much as I could about what I think is wrong (suggesting fixes, but not doing them automatically). BESIDES! Your example shows my point: `<ul>` is NOT ALLOWED inside `<p>`, so your "fix" actually repairs nothing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

using BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = "<p><ul><li>Foo"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

gets you

```
<p>
 <ul>
  <li>
   Foo
  </li>
 </ul>
</p>
```

As far as I know, you can't control putting the <li></li> tags on separate lines from Foo.

using Tidy:

```
import tidy
html = "<p><ul><li>Foo"
print tidy.parseString(html, show_body_only=True)
```

gets you

```
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, I know of no way to keep the <p> tag in the example.  Tidy interprets it as an empty paragraph rather than an unclosed one, so doing

```
print tidy.parseString(html, show_body_only=True, drop_empty_paras=False)
```

comes out as

```
<p></p>
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Ultimately, of course, the <p> tag in your example is redundant, so you might be fine with losing it.

Finally, Tidy can also do indenting:

```
print tidy.parseString(html, show_body_only=True, indent=True)
```

becomes

```
<ul>
  <li>Foo
  </li>
</ul>
```

All of these have their ups and downs, but hopefully one of them is close enough.

Comment: The reason tidy sees it as an empty element is because p-elements are not allowed to contain ul-elements.

Comment: P-elements can only contain inline elements like a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, button, cite, code, del, dfn, em, i, img, input, ins, kbd, label, map, object, q, samp, script select, small, span, strong, sub, sup, textarea, tt and var.

Comment: I would recommend having lxml installed when using BeautifulSoup as this appears to greatly help with markup repair (pip install lxml). BeautifulSoup will automatically choose lxml first for html parsing if available

Answer (score 10):

Run it through [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or one of its ported [libraries](http://utidylib.berlios.de/).

Try to code it by hand and you *will* want to gouge your eyes out.

Answer (score 8):

use html5lib, work great!
like this.

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

Comment: You're the man. I've been trying to figure out why I couldn't parser a particular website. Adding `'html5lib'` to `soup(page_html, 'html.parser'')` did wonders. :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use, below method but **Failed** on **python 3**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
```

I tried below and got **Success**

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
f_html = soup.prettify()
print(f'Formatted html::: {f_html}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just now, I got a html which lxml and pyquery didn't work good on , seems there are some errors in the html.
Since Tidy is not easy to install in windows, I choose `BeautifulSoup`.
But I found that:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
h = lxml.html(soup.prettify())
```

act same as `h = lxml.html(page)`

Which real solve my problem is `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')`.
You should install `html5lib` first, then can use it as a parser in `BeautifulSoup`.
`html5lib` parser seems work much better than others.

Hope this can help someone.