# Is there an html css normalizer that works?

Tags: html, css, normalize

Long ago, I wrote a style 'normalizer' program to scan the ASP/HTML code of a big pile of classic ASP pages (most of which were originally generated from MS-Word documents, so naturally they were littered with superflous stylesheets and massive one-off styles). The style normalizer generated a minimal set of stylesheets and styles and a new 'sanitized' asp/html document, so that the sanitized document produced exactly the same rendered output as the original (verified with screenshot image comparisons).

Every now and then, I run across a need for a program like this, and am toying with the idea of writing one for commercial release.

My googling skills have not turned up anything exactly like this (HTML:Normalize Perl module and HTML Tidy project just seem to clean up tags).

So, my questions are:

1. is there such a tool already, commercial or otherwise?
2. if not, does anybody really need it?
3. if so, what features would make it truly worthwhile?

re #3 for example, collecting a base stylesheet for a set of pages, or adjusting all pages to use a given base stylesheet; preserving classic asp commands, following #includes, preserving asp.net embedded scripts, et al. The more specific and numerous, the better.

Example:
Old html w/embedded tags

```
<html><head>
<title>title</title>
<style type='css/text'>
.cls1 { font-family: arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<% somefunction() %>
<div class='cls1' style='font-size:10px;'>test div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

New html

```
<html><head>
<title>title</title>
<style type='css/text'>
.cls1 { font-family: arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<% somefunction() %>
<div class='cls1'>test div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the style on the div is gone, since it was redundant with the class cls1

EDIT: removed the term 'sanitizer' since i'm not focused on XSS attacks or filtering input in comments, merely on consolidating a lot of ad-hoc styles and random CSS classes into a minimal coherent set of stylesheets.

Comment: RE #2: Well, if one exists, I would certainly take a look at it!

Comment: @[Zachary Yates]: and what specific features would you be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't say definitively that this "works" for everything described, but Tidy does a bit more than clean up tags.

See the [HTML Tidy Configuration Options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html), especially those relating to Microsoft Word (like [word-2000](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#word-2000))

Comment: Always been a fan of HTML Tidy.  I had a bunch of Word-gen'd HTML that had to be cleaned up a few years back, and it was fast and easy.

Comment: @[Ken G]: HTML Tidy does not seem to clean up style='...' (see example in question) or at least i could not get it to do so...

Comment: You're correct, I don't know of OSS that will do that.  XMLSpy (or another of Altova's products) may do it, I believe I've seen other COTS SW that does.  CSS merging is an interesting problem.  I'd probably attack that specific issue, assuming 'Tidy`-ed input (syntactically correct [X]HTML).

Comment: @[Ken G]: yes, that's the way i did it before - looks like i'll have to do it again ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if you've done a reasonable job, you should try [these tests](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/xssAttacks.php) (using something like Tidy you'll probably find you haven't done a reasonable job).

Some options:

- [HTML Purifier in PHP](http://htmlpurifier.org/)
- [lxml.html.clean in Python](http://codespeak.net/svn/lxml/trunk/src/lxml/html/clean.py)
- [feedparser has an aggressive cleaner in Python](http://www.feedparser.org/)
- [LiveJournal code in Perl](http://code.sixapart.com/trac/livejournal/browser/trunk/cgi-bin/cleanhtml.pl)

Anything that uses regular expressions and doesn't parse the markup would be suspect in my mind (and just too complicated to implement).

Answer (score 1):

Old question but some people might still find this useful. Check out http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/. It works well!

Comment: thanks, that's not what i'm talking about, i'm talking about a tool that will scan through all of your html code and pull out all of the stylesheets and object-level styles and create one stylesheet with no redundancies; this is a cross-browser stylesheet - which is cool, but not what this question is asking about

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget beautiful soup

[How do I fix wrongly nested / unclosed HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i'm asking about