# How to get a part of a string using a start character and a end character in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I actually have a string with html. And I would like to parse it using xmlparser. The pb is that some tags of my string are not correct. Especially the `<img />` tags. So I need to replace those tags because it miss the final `/`. I would like to retrieve all `img` tags and add a `/` at the end.
For that, I need to find all the `<img` in my text until the next `>` to replace it by `/>` in order to parse my string.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: XML != HTML. Have you considered using `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml.html`?

Comment: Yes but it should work. I just want to replace the string. Is it possible?

Comment: Karl: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/106302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for all kinds of trouble.  Try a library that is better suited to the task.  It looks like `BeautifulSoup` may be what you want.

If you are dead set on using `xmlparser`, then you might want to use `BeautifulSoup` to clean up the HTML first.  See:  [How do I fix wrongly nested / unclosed HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags)