# Processing badly formed HTML files with XPATH

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, elementtree

I inherited someone elses (dreadful) codebase, and am currently desperately trying to fix things. Today, that means gathering a list of all the dead links in our template/homepage.

I'm currently using ElementTree in Python, trying to parse the site using xpath. Unfortunately, it seems that the html is malformed, and ElementTree keeps throwing errors.

Are there more error friendly xpath parsers? Is there a way to run ElementTree in a non-strict mode? Are there any other methods, such as preprocessing, that can be used to help this process?

Comment: HTMLTidy (http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) can be used to convert an HTML to a well-formed XML document. What do you mean by "dead links"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LXML](http://lxml.de) can parse some malformed HTML, implements an extended version of the ElementTree API, and supports XPath:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> t = html.fromstring("""<html><body>Hello! <p> Goodbye.</body></html""")
>>> html.tostring(t.xpath("//body")[0])
'<body>Hello! <p> Goodbye.</p></body>'
```

Answer (score 3):

My commiserations!

You'd be better off parsing your HTML with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). As the homepage states:

> You didn't write that awful page. You're just trying to get some data
>   out of it. Beautiful Soup is here to help. Since 2004, it's been
>   saving programmers hours or days of work on quick-turnaround screen
>   scraping projects.

and more importantly:

> Beautiful Soup parses anything you give it, and does the tree
>   traversal stuff for you. You can tell it "Find all the links", or
>   "Find all the links of class externalLink", or "Find all the links
>   whose urls match "foo.com", or "Find the table heading that's got bold
>   text, then give me that text."

Comment: But it DOES NOT support XPath.

Comment: @VajkHermecz nope. It does support a limited set of CSS selectors and you can swap parsers though. The latter can help a lot with broken HTML input; `html5lib` could fix the html differently from lxml for a given document, in a way that may matter to the task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) can very well deal with malformed HTML. You should also definitely look at [How do I fix wrongly nested / unclosed HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags). There, also [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) was suggested.

Comment: But it DOES NOT support XPath.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit OT, but since it's the links you are interested in, you could also use an external link checker.

I've used [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) for years and it works great. I have a couple of sites that have more than 15,000 internal pages and running Xenu on the LAN with 30 simultaneous threads it takes about 5-8 minutes to check the site. All link types (pages, images, CSS, JS, etc.) are checked and there is a simple-but-useful exclusion mechanism. It runs on XP/7 with whatever authorization MSIE has, so you can check member/non-member views of your site.

Note: Do *not* run it when logged into an account that has admin privileges or it will dutifully wander backstage and start hitting *delete* on all your data! (Yes, I did that once -- fortunately I had a backup. :-)