# Python - Remove Unclosed Tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

In Python I have a series of messy strings with unclosed tags. Note: this does not need to be proper XML as it is for an NLP parser. For example consider the following string:

```
<hi><TIMEX>every monday, wednesday and friday</TIMEX> </TIMEX>but <TIMEX>not saturday 
</TIMEX></bye><TIMEXUNTIL>until january</TIMEXUNTIL> from <TIMERANGE>11:30am-12:00
</TIMERANGE>
```

We have an extra open tag:

```
<hi>
```

And extra closing tags:

```
</TIMEX>
</bye>
```

How can I easily delete any tags that don't have a matching open/close? The output that I am looking for is:

```
<TIMEX>every monday, wednesday and friday</TIMEX> but <TIMEX>not saturday 
</TIMEX><TIMEXUNTIL>until january</TIMEXUNTIL> from <TIMERANGE>11:30am-12:00
</TIMERANGE>
```

Comment: you also have an extra `</TIMEX>`, right before the word `but` on the first line...

Comment: Yep, I forgot to add that one. Updated.

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags). Try this. I see its HTML, but maybe you can handle custom tags.

Comment: @juree, I was originally looking at that one, but it seems to handle adding the missing tags, rather than removing the extra ones. But yes, BeautifulSoup can handle these types of custom tags.

Comment: Based on the way most permissive parsers work, seeing an opening tag like `<hi>`, they assume that tag encloses the maximum number of following nodes. This is exactly like the "greedy" behavior of `+` and `*` regexp operators. In this case, `<hi>` would enclose your entire document, and removing it would delete everything. Probably not what you want. But that's what permissive parsers like `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml.html` will give you.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the output you want. In particular, what do you want to happen to the bare text like the "but" before the second `<TIMEX>`? Because if you remove the overall `<hi>`, that text is then not wrapped in any tag, making it invalid XML.

Comment: I should have clarified, this is actually part of an NLP problem, not HTML or XML. The tags are to mark text in natural language which will be subsequently analyzed. I have adjusted the question to show the sample output that I am looking for.

Answer (score -3):

One solution can be to iterate over the string, finding tags, both closed and opened ones.

Then put the logic, accordingly. Ideally it can be solved with a stack data structure. Code can be written by using the following logic. -

1. Let a be the tag, either opened or closed
2. check if the tag is in a list, check in the reverse manner
3. if you find an appropriate tag in the list and remove that . If not, add that tag as well, as well its position. Appropriate tag can be defined as a closed tag for a open one or another open tag as well, or a open tag for a closed one.
4. At the end of iteration you will have unclose/unopened tags and their positions. Now you can go ahead and remove.