# pandas dataframe rendered as html shows up weirdly (with literal tags) when included in jekyll site

Tags: pandas, xhtml, jekyll, jupyter-notebook

Repro:

1. [Create a new jekyll site](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/)
2. Create an iPython notebook, test.ipynb, with the following content and run it:

   ```
   import pandas as pd    
   df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5]], columns=['A', 'B'])
   df
   ```
3. Run `jupyter nbconvert --to html --template basic test.ipynb`
4. Copy the `test.html` file created in the previous step to the `_includes` directory under the root of the jekyll site
5. Edit the default `welcome-to-jekyll.markdown` file under `_posts` to add the line: `{% include test.html %}`
6. Run `jekyll serve` and navigate to the sample post

I expect to see a table representation of my dataframe as it appears in my iPython notebook. What I actually get is a mess where some tags are interpreted appropriately and some are just rendered as text. It looks something like:

```
<th id="T_6c043882_e6d3_11e6_badf_889ffafd94e7" class="row_heading level0 row0" rowspan=1> 0
<th class="col_heading level0 col0" colspan=1> A <th class="col_heading level0 col1" colspan=1> B
4   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the attributes such as `colspan=1` generated by pandas. Quoting attribute values is optional in HTML5, but [not in XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495402/262271).

[kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html), the default markdown parser used in jekyll, only supports valid XHTML.

The best fix I've found is to normalize the HTML within the notebook. i.e. replace the line with just `df` above with something like...

```
import IPython.core.display as di
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
def sanitize_style(s):
    soup = BS(s.render())
    return soup.prettify()

di.display(di.HTML(sanitize_style(df.style)))
```

Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293558/262271) for the idea of using BeautifulSoup to normalize HTML. In addition to wrapping unquoted attribute values, it also does stuff like closing unclosed tags, which isn't a problem in the minimal example above, but can cause issues with more complex examples.

If you're going to be rendering a lot of such tables, it might be worth doing the normalization further downstream using a custom nbconvert config file, so you don't have to repeat a lot of boilerplate in the notebook code.

You could also try switching from the kramdown parser to redcarpet (change the line `markdown: kramdown` to `markdown: redcarpet` in `_config.yml`, and add `gem 'redcarpet'` to your Gemfile). This fixed my XHTML problems but introduced some unrelated quirks. Also note that [as of May 2016, Github-pages will only support kramdown](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0).