# How to safely render html in a div in Django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

My view is returning a Model object, that object has a field with value as HTML code.

```
def my_view(request):
    ob = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    print ob.html   # "<div> Description <span> number </span>"
    return render(request,'page.html',{'ob':ob})
```

Some of my html values have not properly closed tags like

```
<div> Description <span> number </span>
```

If I render that value in template like {{ ob.html | safe }}, It's breaking parent elements structure and my page got unaligned as I designed.

How can I safely put that HTML code without breaking parents structure.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags) can come in handy for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix wrongly nested / unclosed HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293482/how-do-i-fix-wrongly-nested-unclosed-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [`bleach`](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) to sanitize the content:

> Because it relies on html5lib, Bleach is as good as modern browsers at
>   dealing with weird, quirky HTML fragments. And any of Bleach's methods
>   will fix unbalanced or mis-nested tags.

You could use it via `django-bleach` which comes with a ready to use [filter for your templates](http://django-bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#in-your-templates).